# How to get single value from dictonary in forloop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've got a dict with info that looks like this;

```
Comp [[' 1992', ' 1992', ' 110.0'], [' 1992', ' 1993', ' 170.0'], [' 1993', ' 1993', ' 200.0']]
Non-Comp [[' 1990', ' 1990', ' 45.2'], [' 1990', ' 1991', ' 64.8'], [' 1990', ' 1993', ' 37.0'], [' 1991', ' 1991', ' 50.0'], [' 1991', ' 1992', ' 75.0'], [' 1991', ' 1993', ' 25.0']]
```

This is what the dict looks like

```
dict = {
    'Comp': [
        [' 1992', ' 1992', ' 110.0'],
        [' 1992', ' 1993', ' 170.0'],
        [' 1993', ' 1993', ' 200.0']
    ],
    'Non-Comp': [
        [' 1990', ' 1990', ' 45.2'],
        [' 1990', ' 1991', ' 64.8'],
        [' 1990', ' 1993', ' 37.0'],
        [' 1991', ' 1991', ' 50.0'],
        [' 1991', ' 1992', ' 75.0'],
        [' 1991', ' 1993', ' 25.0'],
        [' 1992', ' 1992', ' 55.0'],
        [' 1992', ' 1993', ' 85.0'],
        [' 1993', ' 1993', ' 100.0']
    ]
}
```

I'm currently trying to read the data by doing a for loop but i don't know where to cut the data off from one key's values to another.

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    for i in v:
        print(i)
```

This would print this;

```
[' 1992', ' 1992', ' 110.0'] # Comp
[' 1992', ' 1993', ' 170.0'] # Comp
[' 1993', ' 1993', ' 200.0'] # Comp
[' 1990', ' 1990', ' 45.2'] # Non-Comp
[' 1990', ' 1991', ' 64.8'] # Non-Comp
[' 1990', ' 1993', ' 37.0'] # Non-Comp
[' 1991', ' 1991', ' 50.0'] # Non-Comp
[' 1991', ' 1992', ' 75.0'] # Non-Comp
```

What can i do to be able to tell the difference between the two values so i can calculations on them?

Comment: Use your variable `k`. That will tell you the whether the value is associated with the key `'Comp'` or `'Non-Comp'`.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Which "two values" do you want to do calculations on? You have several. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You mean, you want operations like `111.0-55.0`, `170.0-85.0, 200.0-100.0`? If not, please specify the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, use `k`:

```py
my_dict = {
    'Comp': [
        [' 1992', ' 1992', ' 110.0'],
        [' 1992', ' 1993', ' 170.0'],
        [' 1993', ' 1993', ' 200.0']
    ],
    'Non-Comp': [
        [' 1990', ' 1990', ' 45.2'],
        [' 1990', ' 1991', ' 64.8'],
        [' 1990', ' 1993', ' 37.0'],
        [' 1991', ' 1991', ' 50.0'],
        [' 1991', ' 1992', ' 75.0'],
        [' 1991', ' 1993', ' 25.0'],
        [' 1992', ' 1992', ' 55.0'],
        [' 1992', ' 1993', ' 85.0'],
        [' 1993', ' 1993', ' 100.0']
    ]
}

data = []
for k, rows in my_dict.items():
    for row in rows:
        item = (k, row[0], row[1], row[2])
        data.append(item)
```

N.B. it's also good to avoid using `dict` as a variable name, as that'll overwrite the built-in `dict` keyword, which means you might have issues later on in your code if you wanted to use it.

We can use **tuple unpacking** to make it neater to create the `item` variable:

```py
data = []
for k, rows in my_dict.items():
    for row in rows:
        item = (k, *row)  # unpacks the rows variable as individual parts into item
        data.append(item)
```

Then we can do the whole thing as a one-liner using a **list comprehension**:

```py
data = [(k, *row) for k, rows in my_dict.items() for row in rows]
```

Answer (score 0):

As your expected result, let us try this code:

```
for key in yourdict.keys():
    for item in yourdict[key]:
        print(item)
```

and the result is

```
[' 1992', ' 1992', ' 110.0']
[' 1992', ' 1993', ' 170.0']
[' 1993', ' 1993', ' 200.0']
[' 1990', ' 1990', ' 45.2']
[' 1990', ' 1991', ' 64.8']
[' 1990', ' 1993', ' 37.0']
[' 1991', ' 1991', ' 50.0']
[' 1991', ' 1992', ' 75.0']
[' 1991', ' 1993', ' 25.0']
[' 1992', ' 1992', ' 55.0']
[' 1992', ' 1993', ' 85.0']
[' 1993', ' 1993', ' 100.0']
```

as you wish.